# templates: how to control number of constructor args using template variable.

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to make a simple Vector class (math) this way:

```
template <int D, typename T = float>
class Vector
{
  T m[D];
  // ...
};
```

Where `D` is the number of dimensions. If it is two, the vector will store two values of type `T`.

---

How can I declare the constructor function to take `D` arguments of type `T`?

```
Vector<2> v(1.0f, -6.3f);
```

How to add a function only if `D` if a specific number? I wish to add `GetX()` if `D` is >= 1, `GetY()` if `D` is >= 2 and `GetZ()` if `D` is >= 3, but the following code should generate a compile-time error:

```
Vector<2> v(1.0f, -6.3f);
cout << v.GetZ() << endl;
```

How to generate a compile-time error if D is < 1?

I'm not following any specific standard, anything will work for me.

Comment: You can use varadic templates

Comment: Does `Vector<-1>` make sense? :) I would use `std::size_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: @GMan `Vector<0>` also doesn't make sense. Anyway, `size_t` is better.

Comment: @LBg: You could specialise it to make sense, but then it’d be pointless. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have access to a C++11 compiler but maybe something like this could work?

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <int D, typename T>
class Vector
{
    static_assert(D > 0, "Dimension must be greater than 0");
    std::array<T,D> m;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Vector(Args&&... args) : m{T(args)...}
    {
         static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == D, "Invalid number of constructor arguments.");
    }

    T GetX() const { return m[0]; }
    T GetY() const { return m[1]; }
    T GetZ() const { return m[2]; }
};

template <typename T>
class Vector<1, T>
{
    std::array<T,1> m;
public:
    Vector(const T& t0) : m{t0}
    {
    }

    T GetX() const { return m[0]; }
};

template <typename T>
class Vector<2, T>
{
    std::array<T,2> m;
public:
    Vector(const T& t0, const T& t1) : m{t0, t1}
    {
    }

    T GetX() const { return m[0]; }
    T GetY() const { return m[1]; }
};
```

Comment: You should add some `static_assert`s to the `Get` functions.

Comment: I can't get this to work on GCC 4.7. The compiler is not picking the constructor one a call to `Vector<4, double>::Vector(double, double, double, double)`. (and there was a `typename` missing that I fixed.)

Comment: That should really be `std::forward<Args>(args)` in the constructor

Comment: K-ballo: What kind of static_asserts?

Comment: @ronag : Presumably that `D` > 1, 2, or 3 respectively, but I think he missed your specializations.

Comment: On GCC 4.5 (http://www.ideone.com/BukGh) I get a decent error message: "error: parameter packs must be at the end of the parameter list". Turns out GCC 4.5 is wrong in this because these are allowed to be not at the end. However according to §14.8.2.1p1, this makes it a non-deduced context, and thus the constructor is not callable. The compiler should produce an error anyway, it's just that GCC 4.5 produces the wrong one.

Comment: R. Martinho Fernandes: I see, I'll change it.

Comment: Using SFINAE rather than a hard error (via `static_assert`) doesn't seem appropriate, the constructor is not participating in overload resolution.

Answer (score 19):

So I provided a bit of a silly answer that people liked. But this is much easier than that :)

```
template <int D, typename T = float>
class v {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    v(Args... args) : a{ T(args)... } {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == D, "wrong number of arguments");
    }

private:
    T a[D];
};
```

---

You can use variadic templates and SFINAE to get a constructor with the right number of parameters.

Constructors don't have return values so we need to use SFINAE on one of the parameters. And to use variadic templates, we'll need to have the parameter pack at the end.

This means we need to use SFINAE on the first parameter.

Then this means the parameter pack after the first parameter needs to have one less parameter than the dimensions.

With this in hand, we can write:

```
template <int D, typename T>
class v {
public:
    template <typename... Tail>
    v(typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Tail)+1 == D, T>::type head, Tail... tail)
    : a{ head, T(tail)... } {}

private:
    T a[D];
};
```

And now:

```
v<4, int> a(1,2,3,4); // ok!
v<4, int> b(1,2,3);   // error! no such constructor
```

Comment: Very nice! This should be the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't `template<T... Tail>` be better?

Comment: @Xeo No, that would make a pack of `float` parameters. Not a pack of `typename`s where all types are `float`s.

Comment: You *can* use SFINAE with variadic constructors: `template<typename... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if</*condition goes here*/>::type> v(Args&&... args);`

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit off-topic, but perhaps it'll be the least amount of work: Use a `tuple`. Then you get all the accessor functions for free.

The only thing left to do is to make a tuple factory:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int D> struct tuple_maker
{
  typedef typename tcat<T, tuple_maker<T, D - 1>::type>::type type;
}
template <typename T> struct tuple_maker<T, 1>
{
  typedef std::tuple<T> type;
}
```

We need the auxiliary `tcat`:

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple> struct tcat;
template <typename T, typename ...Args> struct tcat<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
  typedef typename std::tuple<T, Args...> type;
}
```

Usage:

```
tuple_maker<float, 3>::type myVec3D;
```

With template aliases we can do one better:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int D>
using MyVector = typename tuple_maker<T, D>::type;

MyVector<double, 4> myVec4D;
```

Comment: If you inherit from the tuple, you can just inherit its constructor (well, when compilers support that)!

Comment: Well, that works. But I'm still curious about how to do it "by hand". Also, this way, I can't add extra methods.

Comment: "By hand" would be in essence the same way as `tuple` is implemented... alternatively, you could just go for `array<T,N>` (like you already do, essentially), and add a constructor with a brace-initializer list. You won't get free move or in-place construction like that, but perhaps that's OK for float types.

Comment: (Note that `std::array` and `std::tuple` are surprisingly similar types; you can treat an `std::array<T, N>` almost exactly like a `std::tuple<T, T, ..., T>`.)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Does `std::tuple` declare a virtual destructor?  If not, then any inheritance should be private or protected in order to avoid potential memory leaks.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: You're overthinking this. Not everything that uses inheritance immediately builds up a polymorphic, virtual hierarchy. Sometimes inheritance is just a tool.

Comment: @KerrekSB - If you derive publicly from a type, you can be known as that type, and if the base doesn't have a virtual destructor, it won't be called if your derived object is destroyed via a pointer to the base.  I don't think that's overthinking at all; it's safe C++.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: The point is that you only need a virtual destructor if you are handing out *pointers to base*. But in this case, the inheritance is purely of internal utility, and your type will always be the vector type, so this isn't really a practical issue. After all, `std::integral_constant` doesn't have a virtual destructor and people happily inherit from it ;-)

Comment: Don't you think that whoever writes `tuple<int,int,int>* evil = new vector<3, int>;` deserves what he gets from it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Good point! I concede; let them stew in their evil ways.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
template<int N, typename T>
class Array
{
private:
    T Data[N];

public:
    template<int i>
    void Init() { }
    template<int i, typename... Args>
    void Init(T Arg0, Args... Rest)
    {
        Data[i] = Arg0;
        Init<i + 1>(Rest...);
    }
    template<typename... Args>
    Array(T Arg0, Args... Rest)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) + 1 == 5, "Wrong number of arguments");
        Data[0] = Arg0;
        Init<1>(Rest...);
    }
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Array<5, int> arr(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I declare the constructor function to take D arguments of type T?

You can't do that. You can specialize for each of the supported dimensions and provide the appropiate constructor for each one. Or you can define a constructor that takes multiple default-valued arguments and ignore those that are not used. Or you can define multiple constructors, from 1 to some upper limit, and `static_assert` if the number of arguments is bigger than `D`.

> How to add a function only if D if a specific number?

That is done with specialization. You would have to move all the common functionality to some VectorBase template and inherit from it, and do a partial specialization on the dimensionality to add those functions.

> How to generate a compile-time error if D is < 1?

Or you could define all those functions for the base template, and `static_assert` if `D` is not enough to be using that function. Now you have just lost explicit instantiation though. You could also add a dummy template parameter to such functions, so you can use `enable_if` and *SFINAE* to discard functions.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Or perhaps inheritance plus forwarding constructor calls...

Comment: "How can I declare the constructor function to take D arguments of type T?

You can't do that" Thats not true... he can use varadic templates

Comment: @Dani: How do you declare it to take `D` and just `D` arguments?

Comment: @K-ballo: The original comment was deleted. It was about how to make a constructor with the right number of arguments...

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry about that. I retracted the comment because I decided to test it out first. And it works! (see my answer)

Comment: @K-ballo: Easy: `static_assert(sizeof...(args) == D, "wrong number of arguments to constructor.");` ;) Or even clearer the way @Martinho describes.